# How to get instance object from constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, instance

New to Java I am figuring out how to work with objects and classes. In the example below I try to create a car race, where some drivers may have been tracked/followed by some other drivers. Particularly, Im struggling to understand whether I have used the second constructor appropriately.

```
public class CarDriver {
 // Here I define some features of that class
private String name;  
private int age;
// Here I create the first constructor
public CarDriver(String name, int age){
    this.age = age;
    this.name = name;
}
    // Here I create the second constructor, where I try to use an instance of CarDriver to involve a tracker later on.
public CarDriver(String name, int age, CarDriver tracker){
    tracker = new CarDriver(name,age);
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName(){
    return  this.name;
}
public int getAge(){
    return this.age;
}


// Issues starting here. Since I dont know how to extract the information about the tracker
public  getTracker(){
    return tracker
}
// Basically I would need that information to figure out whether some drivers are beeing pursued by others. 
public boolean hasPursuer(CarDriver driver)
{
    if (driver.getTracker() == 0){
      return true
    }  else {
      return false
    }  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarDriver driver1 = new CarDriver("Hamilton", 25);
    CarDriver driver2 = new CarDriver("Schumacher", 23, driver1);
    CarDriver driver3 = new CarDriver("Rosberg", 27, driver2);
    CarDriver driver4 = new CarDriver("Susi", 27, driver3);

    System.out.println(driver1.hasPursuer() + " " + driver2.hasPursuer());
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you're not using it correctly. You are immediately overwriting the value passed in as `tracker`, and not doing anything with that overwritten value. It is unclear what you intend to do.

Comment: You forgot to write a question. This is not a chat. You also need to say what you are trying to achieve and where is the problem.

Comment: Hi @Palo Im struggling to understand whether I have used the second constructor appropriately ->Im struggling to understand , have used the second constructor appropriately? Better now with the question mark?

Comment: no. because nobody can understand what you mean by appropriately, if  you do not tell us what is your intent. mckuok below tried to guess what you wanted, so there might be an answer for you, but you need to explain yourself better.

Comment: You should clarify your question a little. It's a little unclear as to how many trackers / pursuers the object can have. If it may have One or None, you will only need a member variable of type CarDriver to represent this, otherwise you will need a List<CarDriver>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the corrected code, explanations are in the comments:

```
public class CarDriver {

    private String name;  
    private int age;

    // You need to store the tracker as a field!
    private CarDriver tracker;

    public CarDriver(String name, int age){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CarDriver(String name, int age, CarDriver tracker){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        // the above two lines can be simplfied to:
        // this(name, age);

        // assign the tracker passed in to the field
        this.tracker = tracker;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return  this.name;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }

    // Use CarDriver as the return type
    public CarDriver getTracker(){
        return tracker;
    }

    // I have edited this method slightly because it doesn't really makes sense
    // to do something like "driver.hasPursuer(driver)". It makes much more
    // sense to do "driver.hasPursuer()"
    public boolean hasPursuer()
    {
        // you don't actually need an if statement here. "!=" already evaluates to a boolean
        // also note that when there is no pursuers, the value is "null", not "0"
        return getTracker() != null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarDriver driver1 = new CarDriver("Hamilton", 25);
        CarDriver driver2 = new CarDriver("Schumacher", 23, driver1);
        CarDriver driver3 = new CarDriver("Rosberg", 27, driver2);
        CarDriver driver4 = new CarDriver("Susi", 27, driver3);

        System.out.println(driver1.hasPursuer() + " " + driver2.hasPursuer());
    }

}
```

I think the misconception that you have is that you did not realise that *any class is a "type"*. Any class can be used as the type of a variable or the return type of a method.

Comment: Super well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can treat `tracker` the same way as `name` and `age`, where you store a reference of `tracker` so you can use it in the `CarDriver` class

```
private CarDriver tracker;
public CarDriver(String name, int age, CarDriver tracker){
    this.tracker = tracker;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public CarDriver getTracker(){
    return tracker;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried that at the beginning. However `Cannot resove symbol tracker`is returned

Comment: You get that error most likely because you forgot to declare a member variable `tracker` in your `CarDriver` class.